# PHP - display an array from SQL and write values back to SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

apologies for novice question, I think I am probably using the wrong approach so not finding answers to fit what I would like to do.

I have a SQL table - I am displaying ONE column from the table using an array. I also have a check box for each row.

I would like to write the column values for ALL checked rows to a SQL table - and also the logged on username ( which I have in a variable ).

I am using POST and SUBMIT but the php code is not being run at all.

```
 <body>
   <form name="TLDForm" method="post" >
    <?php

         $sql = "SELECT id,TLD FROM tld";
         $result = $connection->query($sql);
       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         // output data of each row
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    {
         echo "<br>";
         echo "<input type='text' name='TLD' class='formid' value='" . $row['TLD'] . "'>";
         echo "<input type='checkbox'  </input>";
         echo "<br>";
    }
    }
    } else {
         echo "0 results";
    }    
    ?>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>  
 <?php

 if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST))
 {
 $tld = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['TLD']);

 echo $tld;

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `usertld` (TLD, username) VALUES ('$tld', '$login_user')";

 echo $sql;

 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

 echo $result;

 if($result){
              $smsg = "TLD selection successful";
              echo $smsg;
           }else
           {
              $fmsg = "TLD selection failed";
              echo $fmsg;
           }
 }  
 ?>     
 </body>
```

Could anyone please advise how I can display an array ( from SQL table ) and then write it back to ( a different ) SQL table based on a selection of rows from the array. Thanks for your help

Comment: You want to insert just the *TLD* column value or the *price* column value as well to a different table?

Comment: Give your `<input type="submit">` a name attribute like `<input type="submit" name="submit">`. Without that, you will get an empty `$_POST` array as the return and therefore your `if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST))` failed. When in doubt, always a good idea to do a  `print_r($_POST)` to check what you get in return.

Comment: Your opening `<body>` tags is incorrect: `<body`. This probably causes the browser to render the page wrongly. Also, remove any unrelated parts from your post like HTML tags, this will help both you and us (and please read how to create a [mcve]).

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Al.G - the body tag was causing the issue - causing everything to stop working - thanks. hcheung - I added the type="submit" and name="submit" - this now writes the last line of data to the SQL table.  @Rajdeep Paul - I would like to insert just the TLD column and the current username ( if the checkbox is checked ) - the price column is included incorrectly.   Does anyone know how I can write ALL rows in the array for checked boxes to my SQL table - currently it just writes the last row.  Thanks again

Comment: @Al.G I will try to provide clearer code next time ( 1st post on this site ) - thanks

Comment: Cancel  last edit

Comment: @Shivshav You can still edit your question and update it with the fixed typo and cleared unrelevant parts so that you get helpful answers.

Comment: @Al.G. Thanks for the response.  I have edited my post.  My Question is really still the same.  With the code I now have do you know how I can write ALL rows in the array to a SQL table ( ideally for checked boxes only ). Many thanks

Comment: The first thing to note is that the logical "and" operator is not `&`, but rather `&&`.